# Getting all files modified within a date range

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, last-modified

We have a asp.net,C# application in which there is a requirement to get all the files whose date modified will be b/w startdate and enddate . How can we achieve this ?
Also want to get all the files not modified for last 3 months ?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179970/c-find-most-recent-file-in-dir), you could do this:

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo(your_dir);
DateTime from_date = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3);
DateTime to_date = DateTime.Now;
var files = directory.GetFiles()
  .Where(file=>file.LastWriteTime >= from_date && file.LastWriteTime <= to_date);
```

Comment: Also love this answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13867061/4009972) by @nicholas-carey that suggests `Directory.EnumerateFiles()` over `Directory.GetFiles()`

Comment: Another downvote, seriously? Please downvoters, leave a note explaining the reason my post is bad so that I can eventually amend it and give the community a better answer!

Comment: I suspect the use of "GetFiles". This is first gets a complete list of all files and then passes the complete array onto the where clause. On a file system with a large number of files this would be inefficient. Enumeratefiles passes each file onto the where clause.

Answer (score 1):

look at this question and answer:

[How to find the most recent file in a directory using .NET, and without looping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179970/c-find-most-recent-file-in-dir)

you can start from there and add your `where` clause to the provided LINQ query in the answer :)