# Directory.GetFiles get today's files only

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

There is nice function in .NET Directory.GetFiles, it's simple to use it when I need to get all files from directory.

```
Directory.GetFiles("c:\\Files")
```

But how (what pattern) can I use to get only files that created time have today if there are a lot of files with different created time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this:

```
var todayFiles = Directory.GetFiles("path_to_directory")
                 .Where(x => new FileInfo(x).CreationTime.Date == DateTime.Today.Date);
```

Answer (score 30):

For performance, especially if the directory search is likely to be large, the use of `Directory.EnumerateFiles()`, which lazily enumerates over the search path, is preferable to `Directory.GetFiles()`, which eagerly enumerates over the search path, collecting all matches before filtering any:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Now.Date ;
FileInfo[] todaysFiles = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\foo\bar")
                         .EnumerateFiles()
                         .Select( x => {
                            x.Refresh();
                            return x;
                         })
                         .Where( x => x.CreationTime.Date == today || x.LastWriteTime == today )
                         .ToArray()
                         ;
```

Note that the the properties of `FileSystemInfo` and its subtypes can be (and are) cached, so they do not necessarily reflect current reality on the ground. Hence, the call to `Refresh()` to ensure the data is correct.

Comment: DirectoryInfo and EnumerateFiles is also much faster if the directory is a UNC path over the network: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9cf1ef93-6931-4e90-bb87-28569767fad3/systemiofilegetlastwritetime-takes-a-very-long-time-to-return-results?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: I'm getting an error with EnumerateFiles().Select where it does't contain a definition for select? is that specific .NET version?

Comment: @YA If you're not pulling in the namespace `System.Linq`, you won't see the Linq extension methods. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: your probably not going to have much luck with that unless you also include only the date component of today in the equality check there.. ah I see you've done so

Comment: @NicholasCarey Why do you include the `.LastWriteTime` in the `.Where` part? The OP asked about the 'created time have today'. I'm missing something?

Comment: Because, barring somebody fiddling with the file attributes, `FileInfo.CreationTime` is the date/time at which the file was actually *created*; `FileInfo.LastUpdateTime` is the date/time the *last write* (e.g. the last *update*) to the file occurred. Once the file is created, it's creation time doesn't change, even if the file is reopened and *modified*. However, it's `LastUpdateTime` does change. 

This ensures that it picks up files created or modified  on the current day. And in my experience, you're generally interested in both of those.

Answer (score 3):

You need to get the directoryinfo for the file

```
public List<String> getTodaysFiles(String folderPath)
{
    List<String> todaysFiles = new List<String>();
    foreach (String file in Directory.GetFiles(folderPath))
    {
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(file);
        if (di.CreationTime.ToShortDateString().Equals(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()))
            todaysFiles.Add(file);
    }
    return todaysFiles;
}
```

Comment: I would recommend using `FileInfo` and `Date.Today`, but thanks for pointing me the right way to go without LINQ

Comment: Nicely done, but you could also use the "CreationTime.Date" member to compare the file's date to DateTime.Today, rather than converting each date into strings.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this code:

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\MyDirectory");
var myFile = (from f in directory.GetFiles()
             orderby f.LastWriteTime descending
             select f).First();

// or...
var myFile = directory.GetFiles()
             .OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime)
             .First();
```

see here: [How to find the most recent file in a directory using .NET, and without looping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179970/c-sharp-find-most-recent-file-in-dir)

Answer (score 0):

using System.Linq;

```
DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo("");
FileInfo[] files = info.GetFiles().OrderBy(p => p.CreationTime).ToArray();
foreach (FileInfo file in files)
{
    // DO Something...
}
```

if you wanted to break it down to a specific date you could try this using a filter

```
var files = from c in directoryInfo.GetFiles() 
            where c.CreationTime >dateFilter
            select c;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get through this:

```
var loc = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\");


var fileList = loc.GetFiles().Where(x => x.CreationTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") == currentDate);
foreach (FileInfo fileItem in fileList)
{
    //Process the file
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetDirectoryName(@"--DIR Path--"));
DateTime from_date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5);
DateTime to_date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5);

//For Today 
var filesLst = directory.GetFiles().AsEnumerable()
              .Where(file.CreationTime.Date == DateTime.Now.Date ).ToArray(); 

//For date range + specific file extension 
var filesLst = directory.GetFiles().AsEnumerable()
              .Where(file => file.CreationTime.Date >= from_date.Date && file.CreationTime.Date <= to_date.Date && file.Extension == ".txt").ToArray(); 

//To get ReadOnly files from directory  
var filesLst = directory.GetFiles().AsEnumerable()
              .Where(file => file.IsReadOnly == true).ToArray(); 

//To get files based on it's size
int fileSizeInKB = 100; 
var filesLst = directory.GetFiles().AsEnumerable()
              .Where(file => (file.Length)/1024 > fileSizeInKB).ToArray();
```