# how to A specific getfile These days

Tags: c#, windows

```
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\tbank_file\in\ADCODE", "*.txt"))
{
    MessageBox.Show(Path.GetFileName(file));
}
```

code me is Show message all file in folder. i want getfile A specific today. 
file in folder me.

[image]

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/13865777/1849024

Comment: It is hard to get what exactly you are looking for... perhaps you can use Google Translation or similar to make your question a bit more clear?

Answer (score 0):

To get an specific file, for example created today (inside your foreach loop)
You  can use another properties in **GetCreationTime** or **GetLastWriteTime**

for more information:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx

```
  if (File.GetCreationTime(file).DayOfYear == DateTime.Now.DayOfYear)
  {
        // return your file 
  }
```