# Choose file with the most current Date Modified from directory

Tags: c#

I'm using a basic Directory.GetFiles to find the files i want to use.  But i only want to select only the most current file based on date modified.  Is there a  simple way to do that?

```
 string[] directoryFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\networkShare\files", "*.bak");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179970/c-sharp-find-most-recent-file-in-dir

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
new DirectoryInfo(path)
    .EnumerateFiles("*.bak")
    .OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime)
    .Last()
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than use a simple string list you want to use [`DirectoryInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) and [`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx). These are classes that have the folder/file properties (date/time modified, accessed etc.) on them.

You can then sort the lists that these produce as in [SLaks example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8617704/59303)

```
new DirectoryInfo(path)
    .EnumerateFiles("*.bak")
    .OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime)
    .Last()
```