# Get the latest file created in C# in a directory

Tags: c#

In particular path `d:\Input\UtilityLogs\`. I need to search for the for the latest file created and get the file name and store it a variable. I am not able to get any function which can do it in C# 2.0.

Comment: Did you look at the `DirctoryInfo` class?

Answer (score 1):

See [How to find the most recent file in a directory using .NET, and without looping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179970/c-sharp-find-most-recent-file-in-dir)
and order by `CreationTime` instead of `LastWriteTime`.