# How can i display the latest image saved in a specific directory?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0, picturebox

i'm using windows form to display image and I need to display the latest image saved in a specific directory. any idea please.

I already try this code buti can't convert Info File into image ??

```
 private List<FileInfo> GetLastUpdatedFileInDirectory(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
    {
        FileInfo[] files = directoryInfo.GetFiles();
        List<FileInfo> lastUpdatedFile = new List<FileInfo>();
        DateTime lastUpdate = DateTime.MinValue;
        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            if (file.LastAccessTime > lastUpdate)
            {
                lastUpdatedFile.Add(file);
                lastUpdate = file.LastAccessTime;
            }
        }

        return lastUpdatedFile;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show what you tried?

Comment: check tihs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179970/how-to-find-the-most-recent-file-in-a-directory-using-net-and-without-looping and then your going to have to find pictures using extensions etc

Comment: @horHAY i already try this example but how for an image ?

Comment: `var f = GetLastUpdateFileInDirectory(...);
pictureBox1.ImageLocation = f.FullName;`
Assuming picturebox control on winform - otherwise you'll need to provide more details as to what you need for the 'image'

Comment: thanks a lot @freedomn-m :) it works successfully .

Comment: i just add 1 line of code in the load form. you can see the solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution :

```
 private void ImageForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 var f1 = GetLatestWritenFileFileInDirectory(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures"));
  pictureBox1.ImageLocation = f1.FullName;
}


     private List<FileInfo> GetLastUpdatedFileInDirectory(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
        {
            FileInfo[] files = directoryInfo.GetFiles();
            List<FileInfo> lastUpdatedFile = new List<FileInfo>();
            DateTime lastUpdate = DateTime.MinValue;
            foreach (FileInfo file in files)
            {
                if (file.LastAccessTime > lastUpdate)
                {
                    lastUpdatedFile.Add(file);
                    lastUpdate = file.LastAccessTime;
                }
            }

            return lastUpdatedFile;
        }
```