# How to specify string path for opening excel file?

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, oledbconnection

How would I go about specifying a string path for opening a excel file knowing that the excel file's file name will always change or at least plug in the most recent saved excel file in that folder to the string path? For example,

```
string PATH = @"C:\myFileNameWillAlwaysCHange.xlms or mostRecentFile.xlms";
string connection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + PATH + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0";
```

I was wondering if the folder that the excel file will be in will be the only excel file, if there was a way to specify the path base on any (only) excel file in that folder and plug it in for the string path?

Comment: You would have to get the file name using `Dir`.

Comment: what do you mean Dir ?

Comment: `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles` in C#.

Comment: You can search it by the extension

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the most recent file in a directory using .NET, and without looping?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179970/how-to-find-the-most-recent-file-in-a-directory-using-net-and-without-looping)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this

```
string PATH = Directory.GetFiles("C:\", "*.xlms").Single();

string connection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + PATH + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0";
```

If you don't want it to throw an exception if more files are found, replace `Single` with `First`.
If you don't want it to throw an exception if there are no matching files, replace `Single` with `FirstOrDefault` and add a `null` check

---

**EDIT**

To get the most recent file:

```
string PATH = Directory.GetFiles("C:\", "*.xlms").Select(f => new FileInfo(f)).OrderByDescending(fi => fi.CreationTime).First().FullName
```

Comment: But you are missing the wildcard character before `.xlms` in your search filter.

Comment: @GrantWinney Yes but the OP changed :), edited to match the new requirements

Comment: what reference do i need for the .Single() ?

Comment: You could use the following if you can't use Single `string PATH = Directory.GetFiles("C:\", "*.xlms").Select(f => new FileInfo(f)).OrderByDescending(fi => fi.CreationTime).First().FullName`

Comment: couldn't i reorder it by the most recent added date and get the first recent file?

Comment: @NewKidOnTheBlock You mean the `Added to folder` date? There is no such date stored in the `FileInfo`...

Comment: well anything that can help determine what file went in there first, like date modified and date created yes.

Comment: so you may want to use `LastWriteTime` instead of `CreationTime`

Comment: so LastWriteTime will get me the most recent added excel file to that folder?

Comment: No, the file with the last modification date, as I told you it is not possible to know the `Added to folder` date, the workaround would be to use a `FileSystemWatcher` but it is out of scope

Answer (score 2):

From what I gather from your question, you are looking to get the path of an Excel file that should be the only such file in a given directory. In that case, you can do this:

```
string path= Directory.GetFiles("C:\YourDirectory", "*.xlms").Single();
string connection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0";
```

This will get the files with the given file extension in the given directory, and then assert there is only one by doing a `Single()` call on it. If more than one such file exists in the folder, then you'll get a `InvalidOperationException`.

**EDIT**
To get the most recent file (I've chosen to go by creation time, but you can use modified date if you'd rather), you can do this:

```
DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo("C:\YourDirectory");

string path = info.GetFiles("*.xlms").OrderByDescending (fi => fi.CreationTimeUtc).First().FullName;
```

This has no exception handling, so if the `First()` call doesn't return anything, you'll need to handle that.

Comment: Well if I'm able to get the most recent file added to that folder, that would be even better.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you are looking for all the Excel files at one Folder.

this is the code:

```
        try
        {
        string PATH = @"C:\YourFolderPath";
        DirectoryInfo Dir = new DirectoryInfo(PATH);
        FileInfo[] FileList = Dir.GetFiles("*.xls*", SearchOption.AllDirectories );
        foreach (FileInfo FI in FileList )
        {
        Console.WriteLine(FI.FullName);
        }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message );
        }
```

inside the foreach you can put any code you want