# Identify Last Captured Image in a Folder Using .Net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, picturebox

I have a PictureBox in .Net that displays images from a folder "Photos" using the following code on a click event:

```vb
PictureBox1.Image = Nothing 'Clearing PictureBox1 
Dim bmPhotos as new Bitmap("C:\Photos\ImageName.gif")
PictureBox1.Image = bmPhotos
```

I want to replace "*ImageName*" in the file path with the name of the last captured image programatically. Is there a way to find out the name of the image that was added last to the "Photos" folder?

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179970/how-to-find-the-most-recent-file-in-a-directory-using-net-and-without-looping Probably that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the last created file is what you need, you can find it this way:

```
Dim file = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("path") _
                 .OrderByDescending(Function(f) New System.IO.FileInfo(f).CreationTime) _
                 .FirstOrDefault()
```

You can also use `GetFiles("path", "*.gif")` to limit the result between gif files.

Also you can add some criteria after `GetFiles`, to limit the file types to be between specific file types, for example:

```
.Where(Function(f) New String() {".gif", ".png"}.Contains(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(f)))
```

Then you can show the image this way:

```
Me.PictureBox1.ImageLocation = file
```

Or

```
Me.PictureBox1.Load(file)
```

Comment: Amazing!!! Thank you very much. I tried your code and it worked. I am wondering if there is a way to populate PictureBox1 automatically as soon as an image is added to the folder without me having to click a button to activate the code? Thank you once a gain.

Comment: You are welcome :) To do it automatically, you can use  [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx). The msdn link shares good information about how to use FileSystemWatcher`. You can also ask your question about using `FileSystemWatcher` in a new post :)