# Download the latest excel file from the folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, download

I m storing the excel files in a folder based on `SYSDATE`(current date). Now I dont want to download all the files from the folder.

But I want to download the latest file from the folder which is based on time. Here is what my code look likes. As currently I was downloading all the excel files from the folder in a zip.

```
else if (strSelectedReportType == "RCOMReports")
                {
                    string strReportFile = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RCOMReports"].ToString();
                    string strFilePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportDirectory"].ToString() + "\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");

                    using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
                    {
                        zip.AlternateEncodingUsage = ZipOption.AsNecessary;

                        if (Directory.Exists(strFilePath))
                        {
                            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(strFilePath);

                            FileInfo[] FileInfo = di.GetFiles();

                            if (FileInfo.Length > 0)
                            {
                                foreach (FileInfo item in FileInfo)
                                {
                                    zip.AddFile(item.FullName, "Files");
                                }
                            }
                            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

                            Stream Objstream = new MemoryStream(ms.ToArray());
                            Objstream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                            zip.AddEntry(strReportFile, Objstream);

                            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
                            HttpContext.Current.Response.BufferOutput = false;
                            string zipName = String.Format("Zip_{0}.zip", strReportFile);
                            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
                            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + zipName);
                            zip.Save(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
                            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "Alert", "alert('No Reports as on today's date..!!');", true);
                        }

                    }

                }
```

Now I dont want Zip also

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179970/how-to-find-the-most-recent-file-in-a-directory-using-net-and-without-looping

Comment: @nikhilmehta: thanks nikhil,I got till here `myFile`. Now how should I make it download. ??

Comment: @nikhilmehta:  I have fileName here at `FileInfo file = new FileInfo(myFile.Name);` still it gives me as false here `if (file.Exists)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find last file and download it.

```
    var directory = new DirectoryInfo(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportDirectory"]);

    // the latest excel file
    var file = directory.GetFiles().OrderByDescending(c => c.LastWriteTime).FirstOrDefault();

    if (file == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    var content = File.ReadAllBytes(file.FullName);

    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name + ".xlsx");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.BufferOutput = true;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```