# How can I get last modified XML File in the ordner by using Visal Basic or C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a question. I want to get/read/load one  XML-File('Last Modified') from the ordner by using Visual Basic(or C#). The Ordner contains many XML-Files. But I need just one of them 'Last Modified' or 'Updated in the Ordner.

Could anyone give a suggestion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the most recent file in a directory using .NET, and without looping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179970/how-to-find-the-most-recent-file-in-a-directory-using-net-and-without-looping)

Answer (score 0):

My Approach would be (in c#):

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo("YourPath");
DateTime DS;

foreach (FileInfo fileName in d.EnumerateFiles("*.xml"))
{
    DS = Convert.ToDateTime(fileName.LastWriteTime);
}
```

Now you get all the dates and you simply have to look for the newest one :)

Note: you can select different parameters after `fileName.`, for example `CreationTime`