# Automate last generated PDF using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, pdf

I have a task to click on "Generate PDF", then automate the PDF to see if the data is present as expected. However, I am not able to select last generated PDF.... it takes only the first pdf file. Every time when i click on "Generate PDF" file gets generated --------> example: ("file:///home/tifoso/Downloads/Search by Criteria.pdf"),("file:///home/tifoso/Downloads/Search by Criteria(1).pdf".....etc)

My code so far:

```
public void readPDF_ProvidersList() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("_______Testing PDF file_______");
        URL url = new URL("file:///home/tifoso/Downloads/Provider List.pdf");
        InputStream is = url.openStream();
        BufferedInputStream fileParse = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        PDDocument document = null;
        document = PDDocument.load(fileParse);
        String pdfContent = new PDFTextStripper().getText(document);
        System.out.print(pdfContent);

        Assert.assertTrue(pdfContent.contains("License/Provider"));
        Assert.assertTrue(pdfContent.contains("Address"));
        Assert.assertTrue(pdfContent.contains("Phone"));
        Assert.assertTrue(pdfContent.contains("Email"));
        Assert.assertTrue(pdfContent.contains("Gender"));
        Assert.assertTrue(pdfContent.contains("Ethnicity"));
        Assert.assertTrue(pdfContent.contains("Highly"));
        Assert.assertTrue(pdfContent.contains("Recommended"));
        Assert.assertTrue(pdfContent.contains("Metro"));
    }
```

---

How do i specify in my code that i want system to use the latest generated PDF? It is dynamic and will change every time i will click "Generate PDF"

Comment: There is a way to know files, maybe name, time download or similar. Try to find answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548041/selenium-give-file-name-when-downloading/56570364#56570364

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179970/how-to-find-the-most-recent-file-in-a-directory-using-net-and-without-looping
This can help you

Comment: Thank you i will look into it, i added a line to delete file however, it does not delete.... can you tell me what could be the reason?

Comment: I would like to share the code that I wrote. Maybe it will help someone.                                                                                                                    public void deleteFile(String value) {
  try {
   String fileName = (value);
   File file = new File(fileName);  
   if (file.exists()) {
    System.out.println("File is present");
    file.delete();
    System.out.println(file.getName() + " File was deleted");
   } else {
    System.out.println("Delete operation is failed");
   }
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }